# Modify columns in a dataframe by using function

Tags: r, recursion, dataframe, read.table

I'm trying to modify my data frame columns and positions. Finally I found some solution to do that but I want to do all process in a function for all data sets in the directory and overwrite the real data.

```
kw <- matrix(1:11400, ncol = 19) # to make sample data
kw <- kw[, !(colnames(kw) %in% c("V18","V19"))]  # to remove last two cols
add <- c(kw$V18 <- 0,kw$V19<- 0)   # add new columns with all zero values
kw$V1 <- kw$V1 * 1000  # to modify first col of data frame
kw <- kw[ ,c(1,18:19,2:17)] # to replace col positions
```

lets say I have data set in the directory

```
   kw<-read.table("5LSTT-test10.avgm", header = FALSE,fill=FALSE) # example which shows how I read single data 
  `5LSTT-test10.avgm`
    .  
    .   
    .  
    .

  5LSTT-test10.avgm`
```

how can apply this column modification process to each data separately and overwrite or make new data?

edit output readLines("5LSTT-test10.avgm", n = 1)
you can see 19 columns and think this data has 600 rows

```
[1] "  9.0000E-02  0.0000E+00   2.3075E-03 -6.4467E-03  9.9866E-01   9.8648E-02  4.5981E-02  9.8004E-01   1.2359E-01  6.1175E-02  9.7701E-01   8.6662E-02  3.0034E-02  9.7884E-01   7.0891E-02  8.2247E-03  9.8564E-01  -8.7967E-11  4.3105E-02"
```

Comment: Do all the files have the same number of columns and same general structure?

Comment: Also, are they essentially rectangular in structure? Does `read.table` have any problem with them?

Comment: @Ananda Mahto sorry for inefficient example. All the files have the same number of columns with rectangular structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be another way

Read all the files and store it in a list like this

```
# to list down all the files in the directory
files.new = list.files(directory.path, recursive = TRUE, pattern=".avgm")

# to read all the files and store it in list
file.contents = lapply(paste(directory.path,files.new, sep="/"), read.table, sep='\t', header = TRUE)
```

Next you can do the modifications to each of the dataset in the list something like this

```
outlist = lapply(file.contents, function(x){ 
# modifications 
kw <- x[, !(colnames(x) %in% c("V18","V19"))]
add <- c(kw$V18 <- 0,kw$V19<- 0)
kw$V1 <- kw$V1 * 1000
kw <- kw[ ,c(1,18:19,2:17)]
})
```

and write the modified data into new files using the function below

```
# function to write files from a list object
write.files = function(modified.list, path){
  outlist = file.contents[sapply(modified.list, function(x) length(x) > 1)]
  sapply(names(outlist), function(x)
  write.table( outlist[[x]], file= paste(path, x, sep="/"), 
  sep="\t", row.names=FALSE))
}
```

Writing the data to files

```
write.files(outlist, "/directory/path")
```

Answer (score 3):

With "data.table" you would be able to do something like:

```
setcolorder(
  fread(yourfile)[, c("V1", "V18", "V19") := list(V1 * 1000, 0, 0)], c(1, 18:19, 2:17))
```

Thus, if you really needed a function, you can do something like:

```
myFun <- function(infile) {
  require(data.table)
  write.table(
    setcolorder(
      fread(infile)[
        , c("V1", "V18", "V19") := list(V1 * 1000, 0, 0)], 
      c(1, 18:19, 2:17)), 
    file = gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", infile), 
    row.names = FALSE)
}
```

You can then use `myFun` within `lapply` over a vector of the files you want to read and process.

In other words:

```
lapply(myListOfFilePaths, myFun)
```

By default, this function renames (rather than overwrites) your file appending "_new" at the end, but before the extension.

Comment: Error in fread(kw) : 
  'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 'http://' or 'file://', or the input data itself

Comment: @Thabescity, did you load the "data.table" package first? Can you edit your question to include the output of `readLines("5LSTT-test10.avgm", n = 10)` so we can get a better sense of your data structures?

Comment: @Thabescity, this is meant to work on the files directly from the directory, not on your "kw" object. If you want to see what it would do to your "kw" object, replace `fread(yourfile)` with `as.data.table(kw)` in the first code chunk I shared.

Comment: yes load data from directory using `kw<-read.table("5LSTT-test10.avgm", header = FALSE,fill=FALSE) ` 
I downloaded ` data.table`  package and used your last suggestion ` setcolorder(fread(as.data.table(kw))[,c("V1", "V18", "V19"):= list(V1 * 1000, 0, 0)], c(1, 18:19, 2:17))` 


no luck same error

Comment: @Thabescity, No, You skip the `fread` part if the data is already read in. Try `new <- setcolorder(as.data.table(kw)[, c("V1", "V18", "V19") := list(V1 * 1000, 0, 0)], c(1, 18:19, 2:17))`.

Comment: yes now it works. But when try to apply all files it gave an error

 ` myFun <- function(infile) {
  require(data.table)
  write.table(
    setcolorder(
      as.data.table(infile)[
        , c("V1", "V18", "V19") := list(V1 * 1000, 0, 0)], 
      c(1, 18:19, 2:17)), 
    file = gsub("(.*)(\\..*)", "\\1_new\\2", infile), 
    row.names = FALSE)
} ` 

`data.list<-dir(pattern=".avgm", full.names=FALSE)`

`lapply(data.list, myFun)`

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'V1' not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76534/discussion-between-ananda-mahto-and-thabescity).